# How to suppress the annoying "Skipping running test for project ..." message when running dotnet test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

Please, observe:

```
C:\xyz\code [master ≡]> dotnet test --no-build -c Release -v:q Platform.sln
Skipping running test for project C:\xyz\code\src\Platform\Security\Security.csproj. To run tests with dotnet test add "<IsTestProject>true<IsTestProject>" property to project file.
Skipping running test for project C:\xyz\code\src\Platform\KeyGeneration\KeyGeneration.csproj. To run tests with dotnet test add "<IsTestProject>true<IsTestProject>" property to project file.
Skipping running test for project C:\xyz\code\src\Platform\Contracts\PlatformContracts.csproj. To run tests with dotnet test add "<IsTestProject>true<IsTestProject>" property to project file.
Test run for C:\xyz\code\UnitTests\Platform.UnitTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\Platform.UnitTests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2)
Skipping running test for project C:\xyz\code\src\Platform\DataManagement\DataManagement.csproj. To run tests with dotnet test add "<IsTestProject>true<IsTestProject>" property to project file.
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...

Total tests: 4. Passed: 4. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Successful.
Test execution time: 1.4168 Seconds
C:\xyz\code [master ≡]>
```

The `Platform.sln` solution lists several projects, some of them are unit test projects, but not all. Running `dotnet test` outputs these annoying messages about skipping running tests for projects that do not contain any tests. How can one suppress these messages?

Comment: You're not the only one interested in this. However, there does not seem to be a universal solution, though you may find this helpful (or not): https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/1129

Comment: I have read through the thread, but it does not show how to suppress the messages. Their issue was that `dotnet test` returned non exit code. Now it returns a proper exit code, but I want to avoid the garbage messages.